# InfluxDB 2.x API - check if writting is possible

Tags: python, influxdb

I'm currently using InfluxDB 2.7.0 and python to do my code.

I was searching for a way to check if the database is open and running before writing in it.

So I tried a basic code, and find out that even when the database is closed, the code doesn't throw an exception.
Does anyone know how can I get an exception with this code, when the database is not running?

```
from influxdb_client.client.warnings import MissingPivotFunction
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import ASYNCHRONOUS
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", MissingPivotFunction)

client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token="my_token", org="test")
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=ASYNCHRONOUS)

write_api.write("my_bucket", "test", [("test,location=test0 test=1").encode()]) #I want to throw an error here

client.close()

print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `with` along with `try catch`.The client is automatically closed when you exit the `with` block.

- if you want to check if the `InfluxDB` server is running before attempting to write something to the database, you can use a `try-except` block to handle errors.

> ```
> try:
>     with InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token="my_token", org="test") as client:
>         client.ping()
>         write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
>         data = "your_influxdb_data_here"
>         write_api.write(bucket="your_bucket", record=data)
> except Exception as e:
>     print(f"Error connecting to InfluxDB: {e}")
> ```

Also, use `ping`, to Check if the client is connected to the server before writing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for helping me ! I just tried your idea but your code doesn't throw an error :/ I'm currently using influxDB 2.7.0 desktop version I don't know if this change something